# creating a snake with no mouse or keyboard events

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to create an animation with canvas and javascript. I would like to recreate a snake that runs at the border of my canvas, without assign any mouse or keyboard event. At the moment I was able to move my rectangle from left to right but I can't figure it out a way to make it move down.
Any suggestion? here is my code:

```
function drawRectangle(myRectangle, context) {
context.beginPath();
context.rect(myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y, myRectangle.width,        myRectangle.height);
context.fillStyle = '#FB0202';
context.fill();

}

function animateUp(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime) {
// update
var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;

var linearSpeed = 100;
// pixels / second
var newX = linearSpeed * time / 1000;

if (newX < canvas.width - myRectangle.width / 2) {
    myRectangle.x = newX;
}

// clear
context.clearRect(0, 0, (canvas.width - 20), canvas.height);

drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);


// request new frame
requestAnimFrame(function() {
    animateUp(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
});
}

  function animateDown(myRectangleDown, canvas, context, startTime) {
    // update
    var time = 0;

   var linearSpeed = 100;
   // pixels / second
   var newY = linearSpeed * time / 1000;

   if (newY < canvas.height - myRectangleDown.height / 2) {
       myRectangleDown.y = newY;
    }
     // clear
    context.clearRect(10, 0, (canvas.height - 20), canvas.width);

    drawRectangle(myRectangleDown, context);


     // request new frame
     requestAnimFrame(function() {
     animateDown(myRectangleDown, canvas, context, startTime);
   });
 }

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var myRectangle = {
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   width: 20,
   height: 20
};

var myRectangleDown = {
  x: 480,
  y: 0,
  width: 20,
  height: 20
 }

drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

// wait one second before starting animation
 setTimeout(function() {
   var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
   animateUp(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
}, 1000);`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zfy5atog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the Y value of your rectangle, rather than X.

Changing this line in the animateUp function made box move down in your jsFiddle

```
if (newX < canvas.width - myRectangle.width / 2) {
    myRectangle.y = newX; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah..the effect I want to create is once the rectangle moved all the way to the right needs to move all the way down and then same to the left and then back up...